# Getting wrong ip everytime

Tags: php, ip, cloudflare

So i'm having this code
`

```
$client  = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
$forward = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
$remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) $ip = $client;
elseif (filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) $ip = $forward;
else $ip = $remote;
echo '<script>console.log("'.$ip.'")</script>';
```

`

I want to get visitor's ip but every time it returns false ips. So anyone knows how to solve this problem , or what is the reason ? I also think it could be server-side or hosting problem

Comment: Not technically relevant, but remember that using user's IP addresses could be against the [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation), depending on the context. Consider if you _really_ need to get this information in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your server variable declaration with followings:

```
$client  = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] : '';
$forward  = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : '';
$remote  = (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && !empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '';
```

It will declare+assign it by blank value if unset.

Comment: No it still returns other false ips

Comment: If you are fine to use third party services following js code can be used

`**
var settings = {
  "url": "https://api.ipify.org?format=json",
  "method": "GET",
  "timeout": 0,
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
**`

Comment: after almost 2 years, it's still not correct